# save Matlab data in a .xls file

Tags: matlab, file, file-io, export-to-excel

I want to save data in a `results.xls` file which I want to set its first row "header" with a specific names lets say `a`,`b`,`c`,`d`,`e`. So, basically I have matlab function `func1` which loops `n` times. In this loop, I call another function `func2`, where I do some processes and save save variables lets say `a_res`,`b_res`, `c_res`,`d_res`,`e_res`, I want to save those variables in each iteration in the `results.xls` file, where if the loop has 10 iterations then this means the results file will have 10 rows and 5 columns + the header row, so 11 in total. Could anyone please advise how this can be done in Matlab?

the below image shows the desired output where the first row is headings, then each row after that will be filled with variables calculated in each iteration of the loop.

[image]

EDIT:

Following the proposed solution, I used this:

```
save('results.xls', 'name','number_of_points','blood_level','width','sugval', '-ASCII');
```

where `'name','number_of_points','blood_level','width','sugval',` are variables holding strings. But when I open the excel file this is what I get [results.xls](https://www.dropbox.com/s/t6wmpc3s8pex6uz/results.xls?dl=0) if anyone could please advise.

Comment: Use [xlswrite](http://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlswrite.html), ask if you have any problems.

Comment: I tried using it but I can't figure out how, first problem was although I specified it as .xls it saved it as csv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
p = rand(1, 10);
q = ones(10);
save('test.xls', 'p', 'q', '-ASCII')
```

This works for me. It saves me on the first row the random values of "p" and beneath I have the values for "q". You might check it out. Hope it helps

Comment: I've tried this `results={'a';'b';'c';'d';'e'};
save('/home/user1/results.xls', results, '-ASCII')` but it didn't work and gave this error `Argument must contain a string.`

Comment: i think you don't have to write the whole path, try something like save('results.xls', 'here you have the variable name1', 'var name2', '-ASCII')

Comment: according to your task, you might try: `save('results.xls', 'a_res', 'b_res', 'c_res', 'd_res', 'e_res', '-ASCII')` and you must find a results.xls file _in your current directory of matlab_. I tried for myself, for random values of those a_res, b_res, etc and it worked.

Comment: I've tried this `save( 'results.xls','a_res', 'b_res', 'c_res', 'd_res', 'e_res', '-ASCII'))` where a_res,...e_res are variables, but it doesn't save them properly, like the first three columns are empty then the fourth one has the first 5 cells filled with weird numbers then another two empty columns then 4 cells of weird numbers then another two empty columns then two cells with weird numbers then empty cell then another cell with weird number. Will update my question with a screenshot